# How to insert YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss±hh:mm date in mysql with timezone?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time, timezone

I try to insert this date "2014-06-18T12:32:56.575+**10:00**" in timestamp field. But is saved "2014-06-18 12:32:56" without timezone. How can I convert date to UTC or other timezone?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/mysql-set-utc-time-as-default-timestamp

Comment: @Dan Lowe But how can I get current timezone "+10:00" from string?

Answer (score 2):

Use `datetime` datatype instead of `timestamp`.

As per MySQL documentation:

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>   This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME

If your are already using `datetime` then set default timezone of MySQL or set timezone per connection.